# How Can I kill all the child process created by current running Node application

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, exec, child-process

I am trying to start multiple Node applications within the currently running application.

I have started all node applications like as below

```
server = require('child_process').exec('cd microservices/api-one && npm i && npm start')
server.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    process.stderr.write(data)
})
server.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    process.stdout.write(data)
})
```

All node applications get started successfully with this but now I need to stop all of them after these applications no longer needed to be running.

In short, I have to test node API which is dependent on other microservice so I am trying to create a test environment on CICD server. After test method run successfully I need to stop them.

Any other solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Do you wanna exit from inside the application? Or from outside using something like `killall`?

Comment: @gaganshera I want to kill applications from inside the application without affecting parent application.